# In R > lattice() > densityplot() how can I include the number of observations in the key? With auto.key()?

Tags: r, lattice, density-plot

I'm currently using the following to plot out the ROAS density, grouped by the year in which the ROAS was generated (campaign.year)

```
densityplot(~roas,data=ndb.data.analysis,groups=campaign.year,plot.points=FALSE,auto.key = list(columns=4),main="Distribution of ROAS by Year",from=0,xlab="Return on Ad Spend ($)",ylab="Percent of Observations")
```

I'd like to indicate the number of observations in each year in the key.

Is there a good (easy) way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't give data, so use a built-in dataset. With the `key` argument you can customize your legend.

```
library(lattice)
data(mtcars)

# number observations for each cylinder count
nobs = aggregate(mtcars$mpg,list(mtcars$cyl),length)
nobs # see results
# construct labels to include nobs
labels=paste0(levels(as.factor(mtcars$cyl))," (",nobs$x," obs.)")
linecolor = trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol")$col[1:length(labels)]
densityplot(~mpg,mtcars,groups=cyl,lwd=2,
key=list(space="right",adj=0,title="No. cylinders",
          lines=list(pch=1,col=linecolor,lwd=2),
          text=list(labels))
)
```